Apache limited on how many child processes can start
I have a server with quite a bit of resources. It has 24G of ram and 12 CPUs. When running without load I have 17-20G ram free.
We have been having an issue where during peak times the server slows way down. It seems like it is paging out, but I have plenty of ram free. It never dips below 10G. I suspect this might be apache as the problem, so I tried calculating the required number of processes and setting the conf, but I found that if I set too many StartServer’s then they start up, but then within 30 seconds they all close and only 5 remain.
I have mpm_worker on my apache. According to the docs, the number of MaxRequestWorkers is the total number of client connections that Apache can serve at the same time. With Worker, number of threads is determined by ServerLimit x ThreadsPerChild. ThreadsPerChild is not set in my config, so should be at the default 25. This matches my observations.
I set ServerLimit to 60 and that should give me 1500 simultaneous connections, so I set MaxRequestWorkers to 1500. However, if I set StartServers to 30 I notice the behavior described above, where the 30 startup but then exit, leaving only 5 left. If I set StartServers to 10, then 10 startup and remain. Experimenting I find that somewhere mid 20’s is where they start exiting.
I am clearly missing something. When I startup 30 and monitor ram, it never even barely goes up. This does not appear to be a resource issue.
I am hoping someone has run into this and can point me in the right direction on where to look. Thanks in advance.
EDIT: As requested, here is the conf settings:
StartServers 10
<IfModule prefork.c>
    MinSpareServers 10
    MaxSpareServers 24
</IfModule>

ServerLimit 256
MaxRequestWorkers 600
MaxConnectionsPerChild 50000
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 2
MaxKeepAliveRequests 500
Timeout 300

The problem that I am having is that if I set StartServers to 30 then all processes exit/crash out, leaving only 5 running. When I set StartServers to 30 I changed MaxRequestWorkers to 750
FYI, this conf is auto-generated by WHM, which I don’t have the ability to alter. I can only alter the file through WHM

(it would have been easier to understand your question if you had simply shown us what the mpm configuration is, it would also be helpful to know if this is just serving static content or how the dynamic content is configured).
The "Max..." values are the upper limits. To have plenty of spare idle threads you need to increase the "Min..." values. Apache will start more if needed - the point of having idle threads is to improve responsiveness when demand spikes.
Load should be the first metric you check when you see slowness.

I suspect this might be apache as the problem

Try MEASURING the number of threads - and check for a plateau. You can get this from ps (e.g. ps -o pid,comm,pcpu,etime,thcount -u apache) or from mod_serverstatus.
Update

if I set StartServers to 30 then all processes exit/crash out,

is not what you asked about originally - indeed this totally changes the question. Check your logs for OOMKiller or find the core file.

Added edits to original question
